# XML mapping to objects without attributes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, metadata, deserialization

Is there a C# library that allows mapping C# objects to XML without Attributes?

I have several data sources, all of them containing XML data with the same logical-structure, but different schema. For example in one XML there might be a field called 'zip-code', in another this data will be in attribute called 'postal-code' etc. I want to deserialize all XML sources in single C# class.

Obviously I can not use XMLAttrubtes, because there are different 'paths'. I want something like [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html) (metadata is specified in XML), but for C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XmlSerializer allows you to specify [`attribute overrides`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx) dynamically at runtime. Let's suppose that you have the following static class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<foo bar="baz" />
```

you could dynamically add the mapping at runtime without using any static attributes on your model class. Just like this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        overrides.Add(typeof(Foo), new XmlAttributes { XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute("foo") });
        overrides.Add(typeof(Foo), "Bar", new XmlAttributes { XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("bar") });
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo), overrides);
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
        {
            var foo = (Foo)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar);
        }
    }
}
```

Now all that's left for you is to write some custom code that might read an XML file containing the attribute overrides and building an instance of `XmlAttributeOverrides` from it at runtime that you will feed to the `XmlSerializer` constructor.

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is that when using `XmlAttributeOverrides`, the user should make a lot of effort to store and re-use the `XmlSerializer` instance, to prevent assembly hemorrhaging.

Comment: @darin-dimitrov, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) instances of XmlSerializer classes are thread safe. It means that you only need to make a singleton of XmlSerializer for every XmlAttributeOverrides and then use serializes for application lifetime even in parallel threads, does not it?

Comment: @DarkWalker, yes, exactly.