# To move XML node valus to my custom model

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument, xmlnode

I have string variable like xml structure:

```
string str = "<people><person><FirstName>Daniel</FirstName><LastName>Wylie</LastName></person>";
```

It has 1 node only. I need to convert it to my new model. I converted it to xml firstly like this:

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlquery);
```

Now I need to move `FirstName` and `LastName` values from **xml** to **following model**:

```
public class Person 
{
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I noticed your string 'str' does not have a closing '</people>' tag, is that intentional? If you want to load XML and access the contents in an object model, you may want to look at using LINQ or XmlSerializer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641646/xml-mapping-to-objects-without-attributes-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Use [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)

But because your xml contain  tag. Then create a class `People` for deserialization

```
public class People
{
    public List<Person> persons;
}
```

Then try:

```
XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(People.GetType());
//Convert yuor string to TextReader
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(yourstring))
{
    People mans = serial.Deserialize(reader);
    Person man;
    if(mans.Count > 0)
        man = mans[0];
}
```